# Function '<procedurename>' doesn't return a value on all code paths

Tags: vb.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87x5f80y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

I know the error and why. I am just curious. For some projects this show up as warning while for others this doesn't show up at all.

How do I set up so that the warning show up?

Comment: What version of visual studio are you running? Can you post some code that doesn't show this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information of the warning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87x5f80y(v=vs.80).aspx

Information of how to hide or treating it as error: Goto the **Compile** tab of the **Project Designer**.

**Note:** There is differencies in what type of object you create. In then example below, only test1 will give warning, not the test2 function.

```
Function test1() As String

End Function

Function test2() As Integer

End Function
```

You can also use compiler options to hide warnings or threat them as errors. This specific warning has the ID 42105:
Function or Operator without Return Value Warning

> Generated when the function does not have a return value specified.
>   Default for new projects is on.  ID: 42105 function

More information about how it works here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y20cc1z(v=vs.80).aspx

> When Option Strict is set to Off, Option Strict related warnings cannot be treated independently of each other. When Option Strict is set to On, the associated warnings are treated as errors, no matter what their status is. When Option Strict is set to Custom by specifying /optionstrict:custom in the command line compiler, Option Strict warnings can be toggled on or off independently.

Comment: I am using VS2010 and I get the warning for *both* of your examples above

Comment: As @Matt asked in your Question, can you provide a sample that doesn't trigger the warning?  These are usually "missed" by a programmer using a Try/Catch block in the function and in the Catch part just Throwing the error up to the calling method instead of actually returning a value to it.  If you really want to get rid of them you have to add some kind of Return statement after the Try/Catch block.

Comment: If the Try part always returns something then it will never hit this "dummy" return value, but if the Catch statement resumes execution instead of throwing error then the Return should be something the calling method will handle as an Error/Failure.  Oh, and if you have a project that isn't showing the warning but you know there is a method that should trigger it, then that project has been configured as @Stefan mentioned to probably suppress that specific warning.

Comment: I am using 2010. I open one project, it shows the warning. I open another it doesn't show. Both projects open the same vb file. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: I know this may sound strange and I figure you know this, but on the project that doesn't show the warnings, have you toggled the Warnings button on the error list window? I'm sure you have but just thought I'd mention it just in case :)